# How to prevent a service from getting killed, because process termination?

Tags: android, process

Hi I'm new to android programming. I'm running a service that contains a receiver that detects incoming SMS messages. Android seems to be killing my process on older model phones.
Are there any plausible solutions to prevent this service from being killed when the process gets terminated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Android seems to be killing my process on older model phones

Android terminates processes to free up memory to run other apps. Android will also terminate processes at user request via task managers.

> Are there any plausible solutions to prevent this service from being killed, when the process gets terminated?

No. Moreover, you do not need it running forever. Put your receiver in the manifest to watch for incoming messages, convert your service to an `IntentService`, and have the receiver call `startService()` to send the messages to the service for processing.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding START_STICKY as the return value inside the onStartCommand of your Service class